# user's font size preference ignored

Tags: android-layout

The size of the text will be set in my app in the following way (res/values/dimens.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <dimen name="size_font">28sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then a style will be created (res/values/styles-font.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <style name="MyFont">
      <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_33</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/size_font</item>
      <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
      <item name="android:lines">1</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

And later in a layout:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyFont" />
```

**The problem:**

If I change the font size in the system preferences (Settings --> Display --> Font size) the text size in my app doesn't change.

What made I wrong? What can be the solution?